# .NET Reflector and getters/setters issue

Tags: c#, reflector

I'm using an up-to-date .NET Reflector to disassemble an internal legacy app whose source code is almost impossible to recover. I need to find the cause of a nasty bug, and then possibly patch it. Reflector did a good job as usual in the re-creation of the project's structure, but soon I discovered that **some** property calls were left "expanded" to its `get_()` and `set_()` method signatures, rendering the source code impossible to compile.

At first, I thought that every get/set call had the problem. But at a closer look, several of them are OK, while others (especially OleDbCommand and Forms.Control properties) will be generated as `get_()` and `set_()`.

A quick Visual Studio "Search/Replace" with regex solved these cases, but it's awkward. Is there a way to make Reflector behave *correctly*?

EDIT 1 - Sample problematic code below:

```
/* Generated by .NET Reflector 6.1.0.11 */
/* The variable selectCommand is a OleDbCommand. */
string parameterName = "@P" + Convert.ToString(num);
selectCommand.set_CommandText(selectCommand.get_CommandText() + " WHERE SIGLA = " + parameterName);
/*
   Expected something like this (as ugly as it may seem):
   selectCommand.CommandText = selectCommand.CommandText + " WHERE SIGLA = " + parameterName;
*/
```

EDIT 2 - The assembly was built in Release mode.

Comment: Just curious (for repro purposes), what version of .Net was the legacy app written in?

Comment: @Jason, it's a 2.0 framework app.

Comment: You might try the FileGenerator adding by Jason Bock it should work fine for 2.0 assemblies.  http://www.jasonbock.net/JB/CodeFileGenerator.aspx I also have an edited version that separates designer files for forms here: http://jasonhaley.com/files/FileGenerator2.zip (though mine doesn't work with .net 3.5 features like automatic properties).

Comment: @Jason, thanks for the tip. I'll certainly give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you viewing the source code in Reflector? In the current version (6.1.0.11 at the time of this writing), disassembling a type then clicking on "Expand Methods" at the bottom yields a full class definition with code, including the correct property syntax (`get { ... }` and `set { ... }`)

Comment: Sorry, I meant property calls, not their declaration, which are fine. (I just edited my question.)

Comment: @Humberto: I'm still not seeing this behavior. In my version, property gets and sets are done using property syntax, not `get_()` and `set_()`.

Comment: @Humberto: I've also tested using the Export function, and it also generates the correct syntax.

Comment: @Adam, I'm very puzzled. I did Export too! I just disassembled a sample project and the problem arose in both Debug and Release builds.

Comment: @Humberto: I've been testing it on .NET framework assemblies.

Comment: @Adam, same here. Many properties are shown just fine... it's so weird that I've given up for now, and I'm debugging through other means. Great thanks for you all!

Answer (score 0):

This problem appears with disassembling to Managed C++, right? Might want to disassemble to C# code (there is dropdown in the toolstrip) and you will get the usual properties.

Comment: In my reflector (6.1.0.11) I see normal properties when disassembling to c#. So your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @Femaref, I've included some code to illustrate the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I tested it with my code, and I get the normal syntax. Do you might have any plugins running?

Comment: It's a vanilla Reflector, no plugins. Did you compile your test in Debug mode? Mine's a Release mode assembly.

Comment: tested both, both produce valid properties.

Answer (score 0):

So even if this question is quite old an a correct answer will never be achieved, you can now maybe give the the new tool on the block [**ILSpy**](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx) a chance.

Maybe it will produce some better source code out of the box.